# How do I modify an action method to return a single entity result?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have one Model class named `Product` and one controller class named `ProductController` in which I have only one method.

Model class

```
public class Product
    {
        public int Id { set; get; }
        public string Name { set; get; }
        public string Category { set; get; }
        public Double Price { set; get; }
    }
```

Controller class

```
public List<Product> Get()
        {
            Product product_1 = new Product();

            product_1.Id = 01;
            product_1.Name = "Car";
            product_1.Category = "Toy";
            product_1.Price = 100 ;

            Product product_2 = new Product();

            product_2.Id = 02;
            product_2.Name = "Bike";
            product_2.Category = "Toy";
            product_2.Price = 50;

            List<Product> list = new List<Product>();
            list.Add(product_1);
            list.Add(product_2);

            return list;
        }
```

When I run it, it displays all product data in the browser. But I only want it to return a single result.

Comment: currently this url display all data (http://localhost:50360/api/product)

Comment: but i want when i enter this url (http://localhost:50360/api/product/1) it should display only data related to first id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want it to display data for a single product, then you need to have your action method accept a parameter telling you which one to display, and you need to return a single product. You also need may need to adjust your routing to expect the parameter.

By using the [Single()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535118(v=vs.100).aspx) extension method from Linq, we can simultaneously filter the results and retrieve a single Product.

```
public Product Get(int id)
{
    var product = GetAllProducts().Single(p => p.Id == id);
    return product;
}

//this would normally be part of your data layer rather than in the controller
private List<Product> GetAllProducts()
{
    Product product_1 = new Product();

    product_1.Id = 01;
    product_1.Name = "Car";
    product_1.Category = "Toy";
    product_1.Price = 100 ;

    Product product_2 = new Product();

    product_2.Id = 02;
    product_2.Name = "Bike";
    product_2.Category = "Toy";
    product_2.Price = 50;

    List<Product> list = new List<Product>();
    list.Add(product_1);
    list.Add(product_2);

    return list;
}
```

You may need to adjust as necessary for situation where the client asks for a particular Id that doesn't exist.

Comment: I would use FirstForDefault() .. but same idea.  OrDefault would return null for non existing.......with no error.